# Database Proxy using Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I am totally fresh and noob as you can be on Twisted. I chose a database proxy as my final project. The idea is, have a mysql as a database. A twisted proxy runs in between client and the database.The proxy makes the methods like UPDATE,SELECT,INSERT through its XMLRPC to the client. And, the methods itself in the proxy hits the database and grabs the data. And, I was thinking of some caching mechanism too on the proxy. So, any heads up on the project? How does chaching work in twisted

Comment: a "redis/mysql"?  That's not really a thing, is it?  Also, I don't think this question is going to work very well.  "Tips" to "be in the right path" is just too vague for the stackoverflow format.  Perhaps you could try again and outline what exactly your project is going to do, how you plan to go about doing it, and then ask about whether specific parts of your plan make sense or if there are widely-known better approaches.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use XML-RPC, you will have to write simple Twisted web application that handles XML-RPC calls.  There are many possibilities for cache: expiring, storing on disk, invalidating, etc etc.  You may start from simple dict for storing queries and find its limitations.